# Simple Html Dom как модифицировать атрибут тэга

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Подскажите как это сделать.

Пытаюсь добавить таким кодом

```
foreach($html->find('link') as $link) {
        $link->href = '/css/'.$link->href;
}
```

Но не срабатывает. Вывожу $html и код не изменяется

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не подтверждается:

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');

$htmlStr = <<<HTML
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="1.css" />
        <link href="2.css" />
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
HTML;

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($htmlStr);

foreach($html->find('link') as $link) {
    $link->href = '/css/'.$link->href;
}

echo $html->save();
```

Результат (к сожалению, обнаружил что *simple_html_dom* режет переводы строк):

```
<html>  <head>      <link href="/css/1.css" />      <link href="/css/2.css" />  </head>     <body></body> </html>
```